# beacon chain cannot sync with geth ethereum and error engine in geth

Tags: go-ethereum, consensus, beacon-chain, prysm

I had a problem while run Go Ethereum and Prysm. when both are executed, there is an error response on the Prysm beacon-chain and an error on geth ethereum. here is the error,

Beacon Chain
[image: Error Beacon Chain]

Geth Ethereum
[image: Error Geth Ethereum]

how do i fix it, i have changed the geth section with the genesis.json file but still the error. Following is the code file genesis.json

```
{
"config": {
    "chainId": 12120,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "daoForkSupport": true,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "muirGlacierBlock": 0,
    "berlinBlock": 0,
    "londonBlock": 0,
    "arrowGlacierBlock": 0,
    "grayGlacierBlock": 0,
    "shanghaiTime": 1681499865,
    "terminalTotalDifficulty": 32,
    "clique": {
        "period": 5,
        "epoch": 30000
    }
},
"nonce": "0x0",
"timestamp": "0x6439a649",
"extraData": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006c13615c7ec82f69880ebbca90322aeca7e7090f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"gasLimit": "0x1c9c380",
"difficulty": "0x1",
"mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"alloc": {
    "6c13615c7ec82f69880ebbca90322aeca7e7090f": {
        "balance": "0x43c33c1937564800000"
    },
    "14dc79964da2c08b23698b3d3cc7ca32193d9955": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "15d34aaf54267db7d7c367839aaf71a00a2c6a65": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "1cbd3b2770909d4e10f157cabc84c7264073c9ec": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "23618e81e3f5cdf7f54c3d65f7fbc0abf5b21e8f": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "2546bcd3c84621e976d8185a91a922ae77ecec30": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "3c44cdddb6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12fa4293bc": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "4242424242424242424242424242424242424242": {
        "code": "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",
        "balance": "0x0"
    },
    "5678e9e827b3be0e3d4b910126a64a697a148267": {
        "balance": "0x43c33c1937564800000"
    },
    "70997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "71be63f3384f5fb98995898a86b02fb2426c5788": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "8626f6940e2eb28930efb4cef49b2d1f2c9c1199": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "90f79bf6eb2c4f870365e785982e1f101e93b906": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "976ea74026e726554db657fa54763abd0c3a0aa9": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "9965507d1a55bcc2695c58ba16fb37d819b0a4dc": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "a0ee7a142d267c1f36714e4a8f75612f20a79720": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "bcd4042de499d14e55001ccbb24a551f3b954096": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "bda5747bfd65f08deb54cb465eb87d40e51b197e": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "cd3b766ccdd6ae721141f452c550ca635964ce71": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "dd2fd4581271e230360230f9337d5c0430bf44c0": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "df3e18d64bc6a983f673ab319ccae4f1a57c7097": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    },
    "fabb0ac9d68b0b445fb7357272ff202c5651694a": {
        "balance": "0x21e19e0c9bab2400000"
    }
},
"number": "0x0",
"gasUsed": "0x0",
"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"baseFeePerGas": null       }
```